# SSIS variable as message source in send mail task

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to use a global variable value as the message source for a Send Mail Task in SSIS.

I am using some of the system variables like @[System::PackageName] and @[System::TaskName] to build a message when the task succeeds or fails, but unfortunately, the message source value doesn't get populated with anything when I execute the task.

Can someone please tell me how I can get this to work?

Sample code below

```
"Package: " + (DT_WSTR, 50) @[System::PackageName] + " executed at " + (DT_WSTR, 30) @[System::StartTime] + " on " + "Task: "+ (DT_WSTR, 60) @[System::TaskName]
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to at least show us the code you used. At the moment you're asking us why something isn't working without showing us what that is.

Comment: I *assume* you're using another variable and defining that variable's value as that expression? If you insert a breakpoint on the package prior to the Send Email task, does the variable has a value?

Comment: I created the variable and called it Task_Message. I added the variable Task_Message as an expression in the Send Mail task i.e. @[User::Task_Message]

Comment: OK, but what about it's value at the Breakpoint?

Comment: There's no value at the breakpoint. It's blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've simulated your process, and if I understand you correctly, then the problem is that you try to add "system variable" (@[System::TaskName]) that cannot be added on the variable expression and the reason is that the variable is not a task and it couldn't tell which task to refer to.

[image]

when I delete the @[System::TaskName] its work perfectly

[image]